# UWP Position absolute popup

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp

I have popup.
 When click button in `GridView`, popup will show. I set `VerticalOffset` and `HorizontalOffset` for popup.
But i have problem, when i scroll `GridView` popup not moving. 
I can set popup absolute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup.horizontaloffset#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_Popup_HorizontalOffset) says, the `Offset` properties set the position relative to the application window:

> Gets or sets the distance between the left side of the application
>   window and the left side of the popup.

This means, that the position is set in absolute relative to the window and will not update automatically when the `GridView` is scrolled. Instead, you will have to update it manually by observing the scroll viewer events. First use the `VisualTreeHelper` to find `ScrollView` inside the `GridView`:

```
public static ScrollViewer FindScrollViewer(DependencyObject d)
{
    if (d is ScrollViewer) return d as ScrollViewer;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(d); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(d, i);

        var result = FindScrollViewer(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can use this helper method like this:

```
var scrollViewer = FindScrollViewer(MyGridView);
```

And now attach the `scrollViewer.ViewChanged` or `scrollViewer.ViewChanging` event and update the popup position as you see fit.